# Usage of doesn't in future tense

Tags: future

Is the following sentence grammatically correct and why?

(a) "I reckon she doesn't come in on Thursday hearing that"

I was told that since the sentence is in future tense and I am expecting that something won't happen in the future then the sentence should stay in the future tense so I should have said either of the following instead:

(b) "I reckon she won't be coming in on Thursday hearing that"

(c) "I reckon she will not be coming in on Thursday hearing that"

Whilst I agree (b) and (c) are both correct, (a) sounds completely natural in my head and fine to me so I'm not sure what the issue with (a) if there is one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The awkwardness in the sentence is with the dangling "hearing that", not with "won't" or "will not".

Comment: It's ambiguous who is doing the hearing, "I", now, or "she", when she hears "that."

Comment: In the sentence, it's "I" who is doing the "hearing that" not "she" if that helps. So I was predicting she wasn't going to come in for work on Thursday based on something I had just heard about her.

Comment: I agree that sentence a doesn't sound right (and agree that most off the awkwardness is actually with "hearing that"), but if you change *reckon* to *bet* then *doesn't* is fine.

Comment: My ear tells me sentence A is dialectally correct. If a population speaks that way, so be it - it's correct.

Comment: (A) is completely understandable to Southern AmE ears.